# Starting tailwindcss cli build process stops VS Code live server extension from refreshing the website

Tags: node.js, terminal, tailwind-css, npx

this is my first time working with node, I set up a project and used the command:

```
npx tailwindcss -i styles.css -o ./tailwind/output.css --watch
```

to start the build process for the tailwindcss classes, but this stops the VS Code live server extension from refreshing the webpage, it is supposed to refresh everytime I save the html file, but now I have to manualy go into the browser and refresh it, which defeats it's purpose. Only after I type **CTRL + C** (^C) in the terminal, does it work, but in that case the tailwindcss rebuilding stops. Has anyone encountered this before or is this a beginner mistake?

Answer (score 5):

go to this address in the VS Code :
File > Preferences > Settings, then search live-server. scroll down and check the Full Reload. setting Full Reload to true solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If full reload is not wanted, a longer delay may work "liveServer.settings.wait" : 300 in /.vscode/settings.json. If sometimes fail, a second save will inject the new css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved for me by setting liveServer.settings.fullReload": true in /.vscode/settings.json.